# Paraview: rotate around a given axis

Tags: paraview

The default 3D rotation mode is a kind of rollerball mode.  Is it possible to interactively rotate about a given axis (say x, y or z axis), instead?  I see you can do it by typing numbers into the view details dialog, but that is painful.

Answer (score 6):

While rotating, simply press the X, Y or Z key to limit the rotation to the corresponding axis ([ParaView Blog.  August 1, 2015](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/946)).

Comment: As you were the one putting the request in uservoice, you should have a notification there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, you will rotate around the back-front axis.
I suggest you use the view toolbar to put the correct axis to the back.

You can change the default behavior of different mouse+keyboard combinations in Edit->Settings->Camera.

The name of the desired behavior is "roll".

Comment: right, I am aware of roll, but I prefer to rotate about my chosen axis no matter if it is the "back-front" axis